# making multiple divs with a link opening php pages

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following script. It's making divs with the username on it, works fine until the href part, the php page opens with `user=$user` (the variable doesn't take it's value)

For example  `$user='george'` in the div id and inside getElementById, but in href `user=$user`? why?
Thanks in advance,

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  $('body').append('<div id="div'+'<?php echo $user; ?>'+'"/>');  //$user='george'
  document.getElementById('div'+'<?php echo $user; ?>'+'').innerHTML=
 '<?php echo $user;                                           //$user='george' 
    echo '<a href="account_show_to_members.php?user=$user">   //$user=$user WRONG
      Visit!</a>';   ?>   ';                           
   }
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please...please...please...please fix the code formatting in your post... It is **impossible** to understand what's going on in there... I sincerely hope that your code doesn't look like this in production...

Comment: @Lix his code is pretty straightforward if you edit and see what he originally posted. People on SO could stand to put a little more effort into answering instead of writing off anything even mildly inconvenient. Definitely does need cleaning though.

Comment: @CodeMoose - My logic is like this - if the OP is not willing to put in the effort to post a well formulated question - why should we put the effort into helping/answering? The main idea is to create a reference for future visitors to the site - the fact that we are helping one specific person is just a side effect.

Comment: @Lix - agreed, but what are we teaching future newbies if all they see is us shutting people down until they meet our standards? IMHO it's productive and relevant to answer basics like formatting from time to time, since it also clearly needs to be learned.

Comment: My problem is solved and also I learned that I have to do better formatting. It was my first post, and I was a bit in haste, next time I ll do it better. Thanks agaian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that php wont process inline variables in a string with single quotes, nor escaped characters like `\n`. The first place you should start is changing this:

```
echo '<a href="account_show_to_members.php?user=$user">   //$user=$user WRONG
      Visit!</a>';
```

to this:

```
echo "<a href='account_show_to_members.php?user=$user'>Visit!</a>";
```

definitely look into some formatting standards though, this code is kind of a mess.

**EDIT**: just for the sake of avoiding confusion, here's how it should look altogether:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            $('body').append('<div id="div<?php echo $user; ?>"/>');
            document.getElementById('div<?php echo $user; ?>').innerHTML = '<?php echo $user." <a href=\"account_show_to_members.php?user=$user\">Visit!</a>"; ?>';                           
        }
    });
</script>
```

This can probably be written directly to the dom too, without passing it through javascript. Saves a lot of overhead and complication. Not trying to be a jerk, just giving friendly advice.